# Combine multiple array but when one array is empty not show anything in php

Tags: php, arrays, fetchall

I need help about combine multiple array from database and fetch with

```
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

first I look for data member with percentage of 90% and every data in search in database in subtract one column in query "SELECT", for example like this :

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM tb_member WHERE category = '1' AND gender = 'M' AND age = '30'";
$stmt1 = $this->db->prepare($query1);
$stmt1->execute();
$data1 = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM tb_member WHERE category = '1' AND age = '30'";
$stmt2 = $this->db->prepare($query2);
$stmt2->execute();
$data2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$query3 = "SELECT * FROM tb_member WHERE category = '1' AND gender = 'M'";
$stmt3 = $this->db->prepare($query3);
$stmt3->execute();
$data3 = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And I combine the array with a sample code like this

```
$data = $data1 + $data2 + $data3;
```

I have tried and succeeded, but when one of the array is empty or unread it will error or not display any data even notification error

And i try make "if and else" like this

```
if(empty($data1)){
    $data = $data2 + $data3;
}
elseif(empty($data2)){
    $data = $data1 + $data3;
}
elseif(empty($data3)){
    $data = $data1 + $data2;
}
else{
    $data = $data1 + $data2 + $data3;
}
```

And page not show anything or blank, is there any other solution to solve this problem ?

**UPDATE**

After all i use `array_merge()` to combine multiple array from @Saral and when some variable is empty i use code sample like this

```
if(empty($array)){
    $array = array();
}
```

And then it's work, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You combine array like this

```
$data = array_merge($data1, $data2, $data3);
```

For example,

```
$array1 = [];
$array2 = ['a', 'b'];
$array3 = ['l', 'k', 'm'];
$array4 = [];

$array = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);

print_r($array);

Output:
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => l [3] => k [4] => m )
```

It's weird that `$array = $array1+$array2+$array3+$array4;` gave me `Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => m )`

Comment: thanks for answering my question, i try but i dont know what happend with $data2 and i try using var_dump and result NULL, i think result of $data2 not array , can you explain this ?

Comment: @IvanJuliant PDOStatement::fetchAll returns empty array if there are zero results to fetch or false on failure: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: what should i do know if result is zero ??

Answer (score 0):

The best way to combine array like this:

```
$data=compact($data1,$data2,$data3);
```

or

```
$data=array_combine($data1,$data2,$data3);
```